# Toshiba Win10 Upgrade: No Function Keys (Brightness or Volume keys etc) after upgrade

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard

I just upgraded from Win 8.1 to Win 10, on my Toshiba L50D-B notebook.

Win 10 System crashed - black screen, locked-up desktop function, no touchpad function etc.

None of the troubleshooting worked, so I had to perform a Factory Reset (option to retain my files).

After reset, the Win 10 was fully functional, except that my very top row of keys (F1...F12, Brighness, Volume, Wifi etc) would not respond.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should move your solution to the answer section and mark it as best answer, rather than posting the answer in the question body.

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

After talking with Toshiba Support, here is the permanent fix:

Go to the Toshiba Windows 10 upgrade page: http://win10upgrade.toshiba.com/

1)  Choose your country

2)  At the top of the page, click on "Upgrade"

3)  Scroll down the page and click on the "Click here to get information on upgrading your system" link

4)  Scroll down this page and find the 'Download Toshiba Drivers for Windows 10', then click the "Download Drivers" link

5)  Enter your Series, Model & Model Code details, then SUBMIT

6)  Now you should see a variety of drivers (copy the URL of this page, as you will need to return to complete the last step).  The only drivers we should be concerned with are:

- Toshiba System Driver (32/64bit) -  download this driver first, install it...then RESTART your PC.

Navigate to the same webpage (which lists the drivers)...

- Toshiba Function Key (32/64bit) - download this driver last, install it...then RESTART your PC.

This was a permanent fix for me.